# C++ How to store odd numbers in an array and access them using a pointer notation?

Tags: c++, for-loop, reverse

I found an error in the book solution, the below solution is using the pointer notation to access the array as requested, but the printed results are not odd numbers, instead its printing 1 to 50 and 50 - 1.

Original instructions: Write a program that declares and initializes an array with the first 50 odd (as in not even) numbers. output the numbers from the array ten to a line using pointer notation and then output them in reverse order, also using pointer notation.

Below attaching the wrong solution from the book, appreciate your help:

```
// Storing odd numbers in an array and accessing them using pointer notation


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  const size_t n {50};
  size_t odds[n];
  for (size_t i {}; i < n; ++i)
    odds[i] = i + 1;

  const size_t perline {10};
  std::cout << "The numbers are:\n";
  for (size_t i {}; i < n; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << *(odds + i);
    if ((i + 1) % perline == 0)                        
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "\nIn reverse order the numbers are:\n";
  for (int i {n - 1}; i >= 0; --i)                    
  {                                                    
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << *(odds + i);
    if (i % perline == 0)
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you filled the array with 1, 2, 3, ..., 50, so... (Hint: 1 is 2*0+1, 3 is 2*1+1, 5 is 2*2+1, and so on.)

Comment: @konanrash Just write odds[i] = 2 *  i + 1;; As for the code then it is in general bad. In the first for loop the variable i is declared as having the type size_t and in the second for loop the variable is declared as having the type int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks, yes it's said in the book that // This won't work with size_t for the loop counter because size_t cannot be negative

Comment: @konanrash This remark in the book does not make a sense. There is no need that i would be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    odds[i] = 2 * i + 1;
}
```

And the last loop rewrite using the variable `i` of the type `size_t` like

```
for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; --i )                    
{                                                    
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << *(odds + i - 1 );
    if (i % perline == 0)
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

or like

```
for ( size_t i = n; i-- != 0; )                    
{                                                    
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << *(odds + i );
    if (i % perline == 0)
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```